# My command prompt opens itself periodically and closes itself immediately afterwards. It either displays nothing or displays this message:

Tags: malware

[image: The process "AsusTPCenter.exe" with PID 6496 has been terminated.][1]

The command prompt also sometimes opens itself and then stays open until I close it. I have run MalwareBytes and SuperAntiSpyware and they find nothing.

This is my hijack this log file. I don't get any X's when I run the hijackthis analyzer on it.

http://textuploader.com/kavk

Comment: What does having OS-specific problems has to do with security?

Comment: [Command prompt begins on startup of my computer: asustpcenter.exe?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131222075146AAR7kez). Google is your friend if you search by asustpcenter.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely this is due to malware. If the process was being terminated by an anti-malware tool the tool would be telling you it was closing it. If malware was terminating the process it would be doing it in the background and it is unlikely you would be seeing pop-ups.

AsusTPCenter.exe is Asus software for touchpad gestures, if you google the filename you will see some bug reports of it popping up like this. Although you can't rule out malware it's much more likely this is a vendor software issue.